# How to discover owner from object in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tform

I would like to create a procedure that returns me the name of the form where the object is allocated. For example:

I have a TPanel and within TPanel one TButton. I'll pass as a parameter to the function name of TButton and want the function to return me the name of formuário where is this button.

How do?

LE:

```
function TForm1.DoSomething(Obj: TComponent): String; 
var AClass : String; I : Integer; 
begin 
 AClass := TComponent(Obj).Owner.ClassName; 
 if (AClass = 'TForm') then 
  Result := TComponent(Obj).Name 
else 
 Result := TComponent(Obj).Owner.Name; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
 NomeForm := DoSomething(Button3); 
 ShowMessage(NomeForm); 
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
 NomeForm := DoSomething(Form1); 
 ShowMessage(NomeForm); 
end;
```

Comment: Component names are enforced to be unique within the scope of the owner form but not across different forms. It can happen that you have multiple buttons with the same name on different forms in your application.

Comment: What if the object has no owner? Or the owner is not a form?

Comment: It doesn't sound like "ownership" is what you're referring to. It sounds to me like you want the "parent" control (or the parent's parent if the parent isn't a form).

Comment: Component names are enforced to be unique Within the scope of the owner form but not across different forms. It can happen que you have multiple buttons with the same name on different forms in your application.

What if the object has no owner? Or the owner is not a form?

Actually in my application I have two cases. I may want to spend a specific component or pass the Form itself. What I really need is to know which component belongs FORM or is the FORM itself. I need his name for use in another method. Something like:

Comment: I'm still a bit lost. So you're looking for a way how to find a parent form of the owner of your component (if there is any) ?

Comment: -1 You should be able to edit questions by now. Please try harder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example in the same condition you mentioned.
A button on a panel, returns the name of the form. 
the function ReturnForm, will run recursively until finding the form

```
function TForm22.ReturnForm(aParent: TWinControl): TWinControl;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  if aParent <> nil then
  begin
    if aParent.Parent <> nil then
      Result:= ReturnForm(aParent.Parent)
    else
      Result:= aParent;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm22.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(ReturnForm(Button1).Name);
end;
```

Careful with translations from Portuguese to English:)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the procedure `GetParentForm` declared in `Forms` unit does what you want. Take a look at

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_GetParentForm.html